# jQuery .slideUp() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've ran into a problem that I can't seem to understand.

Here is my code for jQuery:

```
var doc = document;
var win = window;
$(doc).ready(function(){
        $('.t').click(function(){
            $('#Notify').slideUp(600);          
        });
});
```

The code was a lot longer, but I shortened it up where it's just the problem.

here is my CSS for `#Notify`

```
#Notify {
    display: none;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Oddly, this doesn't seem to make anything happen all together, but when I remove the `display: none;` and click the `.t` it will slide down and disappear.

Comment: variable declaration must before your script and not after

Comment: change `$(doc)` to `$(document)`

Comment: @DrixsonOseña if you're talking about the `var`'s, they work perfectly fine with everything else (I cut everything else out because it was super long).

Comment: @Pranavc, notice the `var`'s at the bottom, and as I said to Drixson, they work fine.

Comment: Please post the HTML too

Comment: @Jai Doesn't help my problem, and as I said, they work fine for everything else.

Comment: Guys, the variables are fine. It's bad practice, but it does work. The problem has nothing to do with using `doc`.

Comment: would you post you html markup to see what you kind of structure you are following, seems to me is issue of markup structure.

Comment: removing the `display: none;
    bottom: 0;` property from ur css makes it work fine

Comment: @Outlooker Yeah, I pointed that out.

Comment: Of course the variable initialization should be on top. Try `$(undefined).ready(function(){alert("ready!")});` - http://jsfiddle.net/TA8NR/ - this is exactly what you're doing. If this is "working", it is only because of an undocumented jQuery feature. It is true that due to [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) you can *declare* the variables at the bottom, but you still have to initialize them, and this code does not do that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`slideUp` is not working because your element is already hidden. Change it to `slideDown` and you'll see it appear; conversely, set the CSS to `visible`, and you'll see it disappear.

Here's a [**`jsFiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/remus/83prt/) to play with.

Comment: @user3117575 ;) no prob. It's always the sneaky little things that a second pair of eyes helps with.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var doc = $(document);
var win = $(window);
$(function(){
        $('.t').click(function(){
            $('#Notify').slideUp(600, function(){
               $(this).show();
            });          
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

may be you can do this with `.slideDown()`:

```
$(doc).ready(function () {
   $('.t').click(function () {
      $('#Notify').slideDown(600);
   });
});

var doc = document;
var win = window;
```

[Fiddle for .slideDown()](http://jsfiddle.net/sm4RJ/)

or you can try with `.slideToggle()` too.

[Fiddle for .slideToggle()](http://jsfiddle.net/kx6kT/)

Comment: The SlideToggle Worked Perfect, that what I was looking for thanks man

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery slideUp documentation](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)

Based on your edit, it appears as though you're trying to make the item display after being hidden. slideUp is intended for getting items to perform an animation sliding upwards, like window blinds, and then ultimately being hidden, not being shown.

Perhaps you are looking for [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)?

Comment: Yeah, I thought the `down` and `up` meant the direction it was sliding.

Comment: Or: `slideToggle()`